# Compilar pango: ERROR: Tried to override dependency 'glib-2.0' which has already been resolved or overridden

Tags: c, bash, compilar, pango

Estoy tratando de compilar **Pango**:

```
./make-release.sh
```

Las últimas líneas de la salida de la consola de bash:

```
glib| Checking if "atomic ops define" compiles: YES
glib| Run-time dependency threads found: YES
glib| Header <pthread.h> has symbol "pthread_attr_setstacksize" : YES
glib| Header <pthread.h> has symbol "pthread_attr_setinheritsched" : YES
glib| Header <pthread.h> has symbol "pthread_condattr_setclock" : YES
glib| Header <pthread.h> has symbol "pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np" : NO
glib| Header <pthread.h> has symbol "pthread_getname_np" : YES
glib| Header <sys/syscall.h> has symbol "SYS_sched_getattr" : YES
glib| Checking if "pthread_setname_np(const char*)" with dependency threads links: NO
glib| Checking if "pthread_setname_np(pthread_t, const char*)" with dependency threads links: YES
glib| Checking if "stack grows check" runs: NO (1)
glib| Checking for function "iconv_open" : YES
glib| Run-time dependency libpcre found: YES 8.39
glib| Library m found: YES
glib| Run-time dependency libffi found: YES 3.2.1
glib| Run-time dependency zlib found: YES 1.2.11
glib| Checking for function "ngettext" : YES
glib| Checking for function "bind_textdomain_codeset" : YES
glib| Run-time dependency mount found: YES 2.27.0
glib| Run-time dependency libselinux found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
glib| Checking for function "getxattr" : YES
glib| Has header "sys/xattr.h" : YES
glib| Checking if "XATTR_NOFOLLOW" compiles: NO
glib| Checking for function "strlcpy" : NO
glib| Checking if "/proc/self/cmdline" runs: YES
glib| Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
glib| Program bash found: YES (/bin/bash)
glib| Run-time dependency bash-completion found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
glib| Program sh found: YES (/bin/sh)
glib| Program env found: YES (/bin/env)
glib| Configuring glibconfig.h using configuration
glib| Dependency sysprof-capture-4 skipped: feature sysprof disabled

subprojects/glib/glib/meson.build:408:8: ERROR: Tried to override dependency 'glib-2.0' which has already been resolved or overridden at /initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/meson.build:206:

A full log can be found at /initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/release_build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

Error:

> subprojects/glib/glib/meson.build:408:8: ERROR: Tried to override dependency 'glib-2.0' which has already been resolved or overridden at /initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/meson.build:206:

> A full log can be found at /initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/release_build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt

***/initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/meson.build:206:***

```
# gobject
glib_dep = dependency('glib-2.0', version: glib_req_version,
                      fallback: ['glib', 'libglib_dep'])
```

***/initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/release_build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt***

```
static int
__getcmdline (void)
{
/* This code is a dumbed-down version of g_file_get_contents() */
#ifndef O_BINARY
#define O_BINARY 0
#endif
#define BUFSIZE 1024
  char result[BUFSIZE];
  struct stat stat_buf;

  int fd = open ("/proc/self/cmdline", O_RDONLY|O_BINARY);
  if (fd < 0)
    exit (1);
  if (fstat (fd, &stat_buf))
    exit (1);

  if (stat_buf.st_size > 0 && S_ISREG (stat_buf.st_mode))
    {
      if (read (fd, result, BUFSIZE) <= 0)
        exit (1);
    }
  else
    {
      FILE *f = fdopen (fd, "r");
      if (f == NULL)
        exit (1);

      if (fread (result, 1, BUFSIZE, f) <= 0)
        exit (1);
    }

  return 0;
}

int
main (void)
{
  exit (__getcmdline ());
}
Compiler stdout:
 
Compiler stderr:
 /initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/release_build/meson-private/tmp0qbpsv3c/testfile.c: In function '__getcmdline':
/initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/release_build/meson-private/tmp0qbpsv3c/testfile.c:26:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'read'; did you mean 'fread'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   26 |       if (read (fd, result, BUFSIZE) <= 0)
      |           ^~~~
      |           fread

Program stdout:


Program stderr:


Checking if "/proc/self/cmdline" runs: YES
Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
Program bash found: YES (/bin/bash)
Pkg-config binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Determining dependency 'bash-completion' with pkg-config executable '/usr/bin/pkg-config'
env[PKG_CONFIG_PATH]: 
env[PKG_TAB_COMPLETION]: true
Called `/usr/bin/pkg-config --modversion bash-completion` -> 1

CMake binary for MachineChoice.HOST is cached.
Preliminary CMake check failed. Aborting.
Run-time dependency bash-completion found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Program sh found: YES (/bin/sh)
Program env found: YES (/bin/env)
Configuring glibconfig.h using configuration
Dependency sysprof-capture-4 skipped: feature sysprof disabled

subprojects/glib/glib/meson.build:408:8: ERROR: Tried to override dependency 'glib-2.0' which has already been resolved or overridden at /initrd/mnt/dev_save/descargas/pango-master/pango-master/meson.build:206:
```

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es, en vez de bajar `master.zip`, mejor clonar el repositorio con `git clone`:

```
git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente el problema es que estas reescribiendo la dependencia, creo que la forma correcta seria la siguiente:

En pango-master/meson.build:

Elimina:

```
# gobject
glib_dep = dependency('glib-2.0', version: glib_req_version,
                      fallback: ['glib', 'libglib_dep'])
```

Agrega:

```
    if meson.version().version_compare('>=0.54.0')
  meson.override_dependency('glib-2.0', libglib_dep)
endif
```

El cual primero comprobará antes de escribir la libreria.